# VB.NET Looping a String to a set Number

Tags: vb.net, string, loops, encoding, character

Suppose I need to add the ASCII version of each character in the word "hello" to "hi" so that the result would be something like this: (h+h =  )(e+i =  )(l+h =  )(l+i =  )(o+h =  ) etc how would I go about looping the "hi" string?

I have already managed to loop the "hello" string, but not quite sure how to do the second without getting (h+h =  )(h+i =  )(e+h =  )(e+i =  ) etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? Maybe that also makes the question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Mod` opreator to make the index start over. Example:

```
Dim str1 as String = "hello"
Dim str2 as String = "hi"

' This gets the length of the longest string
Dim longest = Math.Max(str1.Length, str2.Length)

' This loops though all characters
' The Mod operator makes the index wrap over for the shorter string
For i As Integer = 0 To longest - 1
  Console.Write(str1(i Mod str1.Length))
  Console.WriteLine(str2(i Mod str2.Length))
Next
```

Output:

```
hh
ei
lh
li
oh
```